# Why is this question listed as deleted twice by the same user?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

OK, the user is RegDwight.  [This deleted question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/4385/10041) (you can only see it if you have >=10000 rep) has a notification which states:

> **deleted by RegDwight Ѭſ道♦, RegDwight Ѭſ道♦ Mar 2 at 11:42**

Oh, and here's a screenshot excerpt:

[image: deletedtwice]

Did Reg think it especially needed to be deleted?  And why have I never seen this before?

Comment: I wonder if he voted to delete, and then got mod powers. So before, his votes to delete just counted towards the three to delete. Then after, he had supervote and simply voted to delete again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The last elections ended on March first](https://english.stackexchange.com/election), while the question you are referring to was deleted on March second. This means RegDwight voted to delete the question before becoming moderator (he was already a 10k user), and then voted to delete the question again, when he was already moderator, and his vote was a binding vote.